# Is the mail account compromised or is there any other chance?

Tags: email, postfix

The server was sending spam, now it is my task to clean it up. So did a few things which solved a problem, but this is still open. It seems that the owner receives mails from hisself. A forwarding from info@domain.A to mail@domain.B is in place. The mail header looks like the following:

```
From:   27 2021 <>
X-Account-Key:  account1
X-UIDL: UID2733-1620041375
X-Mozilla-Status:   0001
X-Mozilla-Status2:  00000000
X-Mozilla-Keys: 
Return-Path:    <info@domain.A>
X-Original-To:  mail@domain.B
Delivered-To:   mail@domain.B
Received:   from domain.A (domain.A [1.2.3.4]) by domain.B (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 5E1A72008B for <mail@domain.B>; Thu, 1 Jul 2021 22:34:40 +0200 (CEST)
Received:   by domain.A (Postfix, from userid 30) id 44B4138173D; Thu, 1 Jul 2021 22:34:40 +0200 (CEST)
X-Original-To:  info@domain.A
Delivered-To:   info@domain.A
Received:   from hp0.221.gvbni.club (hp0.221.gvbni.club [159.65.219.21]) by domain.A (Postfix) with ESMTPS id E8F7F380E19 for <info@domain.A>; Thu, 1 Jul 2021 22:34:39 +0200 (CEST)
From:   domain.A <info@domain.A>
To: info@domain.A
Subject:    Notice from domain.A 30th June 2021 Error Report #496511148735
Date:   1 Jul 2021 13:34:38 -0700
Message-ID: <20210701133438.4F3F959FAAE23414@domain.A>
MIME-Version:   1.0
Content-Type:   text/html
Content-Transfer-Encoding:  quoted-printable
```

Plesk with postfix is in use, the mail queue is empty. The owner of info@domain.A did not send the message. Of course, this is possible with an compromised mail account. Is there any other possibility why this can happen?

Thank you very much

PS: log shows the following:

```
Jul  1 22:34:39 h2086526 postfix/smtpd[6949]: connect from hp0.221.gvbni.club[159.65.219.21]
Jul  1 22:34:39 h2086526 postfix/smtpd[6949]: E8F7F380E19: client=hp0.221.gvbni.club[159.65.219.21]
Jul  1 22:34:40 h2086526 postfix/cleanup[7201]: E8F7F380E19: message-id=<20210701133438.4F3F959FAAE23414@domain.A>
Jul  1 22:34:40 h2086526 check-quota[7204]: Starting the check-quota filter...
Jul  1 22:34:40 h2086526 /usr/lib/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[672]: handlers_stderr: SKIP
Jul  1 22:34:40 h2086526 /usr/lib/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[672]: SKIP during call 'check-quota' handler
Jul  1 22:34:40 h2086526 postfix/qmgr[28667]: E8F7F380E19: from=<info@domain.A>, size=3932, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  1 22:34:40 h2086526 postfix-local[7206]: postfix-local: from=info@domain.A, to=info@domain.A, dirname=/var/qmail/mailnames
Jul  1 22:34:40 h2086526 dk_check[7207]: Starting the dk_check filter...
Jul  1 22:34:40 h2086526 dk_check[7207]: DKIM verify result: DKIM Feed: No signature
Jul  1 22:34:40 h2086526 check-quota[7212]: Starting the check-quota filter...
Jul  1 22:34:40 h2086526 plesk sendmail[7211]: handlers_stderr: SKIP
Jul  1 22:34:40 h2086526 plesk sendmail[7211]: SKIP during call 'check-quota' handler
Jul  1 22:34:40 h2086526 postfix/pickup[4154]: 44B4138173D: uid=30 from=<info@domain.A>
Jul  1 22:34:40 h2086526 postfix/cleanup[7201]: 44B4138173D: message-id=<20210701133438.4F3F959FAAE23414@domain.A>
Jul  1 22:34:40 h2086526 postfix/qmgr[28667]: 44B4138173D: from=<info@domain.A>, size=4101, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  1 22:34:40 h2086526 postfix/pipe[7205]: E8F7F380E19: to=<info@domain.A>, relay=plesk_virtual, delay=0.45, delays=0.38/0/0/0.06, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via plesk_virtual service)
Jul  1 22:34:40 h2086526 postfix/qmgr[28667]: E8F7F380E19: removed
Jul  1 22:34:40 h2086526 postfix/smtp[7217]: 44B4138173D: to=<mail@domain.B>, relay=domain.B[1.2.3.4]:25, delay=0.15, delays=0/0.01/0.06/0.08, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 5E1A72008B)
Jul  1 22:34:40 h2086526 postfix/qmgr[28667]: 44B4138173D: removed
Jul  1 22:34:40 h2086526 postfix/smtpd[6949]: disconnect from hp0.221.gvbni.club[159.65.219.21]
```

PPS: A valid mail was send from testmail@web.de to support@domain.A, forwarded to support@domain.B:

```
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 postfix/smtpd[31806]: connect from mout.web.de[212.227.15.4]
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 postfix/smtpd[31806]: 2BEA8380E17: client=mout.web.de[212.227.15.4]
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 postfix/cleanup[31873]: 2BEA8380E17: message-id=<1269DDAE-17B0-466B-A309-67FA2688FD76@web.de>
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 check-quota[31876]: Starting the check-quota filter...
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 /usr/lib/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[672]: handlers_stderr: SKIP
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 /usr/lib/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[672]: SKIP during call 'check-quota' handler
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 postfix/qmgr[28667]: 2BEA8380E17: from=<testmail@web.de>, size=2775, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 postfix-local[31878]: postfix-local: from=testmail@web.de, to=support@domain.A, dirname=/var/qmail/mailnames
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 dk_check[31879]: Starting the dk_check filter...
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 dk_check[31879]: DKIM verify result: Success
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 postfix/smtpd[31806]: disconnect from mout.web.de[212.227.15.4]
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 dovecot: service=lda, user=support@domain.A, ip=[]. msgid=<1269DDAE-17B0-466B-A309-67FA2688FD76@web.de>: saved mail to INBOX
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 check-quota[31890]: Starting the check-quota filter...
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 plesk sendmail[31889]: handlers_stderr: SKIP
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 plesk sendmail[31889]: SKIP during call 'check-quota' handler
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 postfix/pickup[29043]: 707C738173E: uid=30 from=<SRS0=RS5/=L6=web.de=testmail@domain.A>
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 postfix/cleanup[31873]: 707C738173E: message-id=<1269DDAE-17B0-466B-A309-67FA2688FD76@web.de>
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 postfix/qmgr[28667]: 707C738173E: from=<SRS0=RS5/=L6=web.de=testmail@domain.A>, size=3027, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 postfix/pipe[31877]: 2BEA8380E17: to=<support@domain.A>, relay=plesk_virtual, delay=0.3, delays=0.15/0/0/0.15, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via plesk_virtual service)
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 postfix/qmgr[28667]: 2BEA8380E17: removed
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 postfix/smtp[31895]: 707C738173E: to=<support@domain.B>, relay=domain.B[1.2.3.4]:25, delay=0.21, delays=0/0.01/0.09/0.11, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 8E7C1201F7)
Jul  6 20:35:36 h2086526 postfix/qmgr[28667]: 707C738173E: removed
```

Comment: Is the sender really A's standard MX? Have you checked the logs on A? What do they show? A claims it's received from uid 30, have you checked which user this is in `/etc/passwd`?

Comment: A lot todo, I know...
User with id 30 is: popuser:x:30:31:POP3 service user

I added the logs in the first post.

Comment: Is what the logs shows *normal*, e.g. what would be shown for a legitimate mail? And why wold popuser send emails? What software is running as popuser on the system concerned?

Comment: Thank you very much, I added the logs in the first post.

Comment: It looks like the server 159.65.219.21 sends mails from a foreign domain or do you have an other idea?